# Java - unable to map JSON array to object with Spring getForObject()

Tags: java, arrays, rest, dictionary, spring-android

I have to consume an API RESTful web service. At the moment I have to deal with a JSON object which looks like:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "error":"",
  "message":"",
  "data":[
     ["USD","US Dollar","11,696", "connected"],
     ["EUR","Euro","10,733","connected"]
  ]
}
```

And this is the class I use in general to hold most endpoints of this web service:

```
public class Response {
    public boolean success;
    private String error;
    private String message;        
    private List<Map<Integer, Array>> data;

    public String getError() {
        return this.error;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }

    public Map<Integer,Array> getData() {
        return this.data.get(0);
    }
}
```

When running, app crashes with:

```
Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap 
     out of START_ARRAY token
```

Comment: `private List<Map<Integer, Array>> data;` what is that supposed to map to?

Comment: it's supposed to map "data" as like in the example I provided

Comment: I was trying to nudge you in the direction of that is completely wrong for what you are trying to map.

Comment: oh...didnt got it then :) could you please spend 5 minutes to answer? thank you

Comment: based on your comment below, your description of data does not match the example. But sounds like you could try List<Map<Integer, String>>

Comment: i found the answer myself, testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out that what i need is just:

```
private List<ArrayList<String>> data;
```

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

We need to change the type of 'data' from

```
List<Map<Integer, Array>>
```

to

```
List<List<String>>
```

Comment: Thank you for you interest, but seems that it doesnt work. I get now: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "data" ... Indeed, the 2nd level in the nested array is not a List of Strings, but rather an array with int as key and an array of strings as value ..